# Why is my RadioButtonList selectedValue empty?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMedicationTime" runat="server"  onselectedindexchanged="rblMedicationTime_SelectedIndexChanged"  DataSourceID="dtsMedicationTime" DataTextField="LookupItem" DataValueField="Id"  AutoPostBack="true"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

On page load, I want to select a radio button from the list and set its value, for which I have written this line of code:

```
rblMedicationTime.SelectedValue = clientMedicationSchedule.glTypeId.ToString();
```

The RadioButtonList is populating successfully, but the value is unable to be selected.

`rblMedicationTime.SelectedValue` is always "" when I debug the code.

Comment: I do think you need to use `SelectedText` or `Selected.Value`

Comment: why not this? what's the problem here?

Comment: It's all about the control itself and how .NET and the DropDownList control all tight up, you can read more Googling it. There are several controls that do not populate `SelectedValue`, a `DropDownList` for example.

Comment: I have used selectedValue with dropdownlist thousands of time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use

```
string myValue = myRadioButtonList.SelectedItem.Value
```

The property object `myRadioButtonList.SelectedItem` contains all values from the selected item of a Radio Button list or a DropDown list

---

to set the value programmatically all you have to do is:

```
myRadioButtonList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

You can see that you have several ways to Get but **only one** to Set:

- `myRadioButtonList.SelectedIndex` --> Gets or Sets
- `myRadioButtonList.SelectedValue` --> Gets
- `myRadioButtonList.SelectedItem` --> Gets

Comment: I don't want to get value. I want to set value so that a radio button must be selected according to the value i am setting.

Comment: I did `myRadioButtonList.SelectedItem.Value = myValue.tostring();` It is also not working

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the selected radiobutton with `.SelectedValue`, only with `.SelectedIndex`.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) (at SelectedValue it says "Gets the value", at SelectedIndex is says "Gets or sets")

Comment: The page says "Gets the value ... or selects the item"

Comment: @anphu Yes, neither of those mean "set" which is what OP wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in `!IsPostBack`.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
string str = rblMedicationTime.SelectedValue;
}
```

First you should check !IspostBack

Answer (score 0):

hello friend there is something another problem in your code because in my side this is running fine.

rblMedicationTime.SelectedValue = clientMedicationSchedule.glTypeId.ToString();

can u cehck that clientMedicationSchedule.glTypeId.ToString() this contain value or not.
and on page load u put selection code on if (!IsPostBack){} block.

Comment: yes that is containing value. I have got the problem. My radio button list was not populating properly. Now I debugged again and got the problematic area. Thanx guys